# Multiroute to headphones and USB (or HDMI)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiosession, audiokit

It seems that AudioKit supports multiroute session category. But I can't figure out how to use it ...

I want to send the same audio stream (coming from a AKNode) both to a stereo USB soundcard (using camera kit, but that might be the same for HDMI) and to the standard headphones (at the same time)

I can't find any simple example (in swift 4) for that.

Any help would be highly appreciated !
Thanks !